# Are the values ​of column xy of df1 also present in column zy of df2?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes and I want to check which value of df1 in col1 also occurs in df2 in col1. If it occurs: a 1 in col2_new, otherwise a 0. Is it best to do this using a list? So column of df1 converted into list and then a loop over the column of the other data frame or is there a more elegant way?

**df1 (before):**

| index | col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |

**df2:**

| index | col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | e |
| 3 | b |

**df1 (after):**

| index | col1 | col2_new |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 2 | b | 1 |
| 3 | c | 0 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with converting mask to integers:

```
df1['col2_new'] = df1['col1'].isin(df2['col1']).astype(int)
```

Or:

```
df1['col2_new'] = np.where(df1['col1'].isin(df2['col1']), 1, 0)
```